# Hadith about dua before eating

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, source-identification, sunnah

I heard that the dua before starting to eat is

"بسم الله وعلى بركة الله" " bismillahi wa'alaa barakatillah "

In which hadith the above dua exists?

do we say it 1 time or 3 times?

Comment: http://www.islamicacademy.org/html/Articles/Anwar-ul-Hadees/English/Etiquette_of_Eating.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assalamu alaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh,

The phrase  بسم الله وعلى بركة الله (Bismillahi wa'alaa barakatillah) is not found in any books of hadeeth as far as I know. But the phrase  بسم الله وبركة الله (Bismillahi wa barakatillah) omitting the 'alaa is found in the Mustadrak of Imam Hakim, from Abdullah Ibn Abbas (may Allah be pleased with him).

But the most authentic ahadeeth in this aspect is found in many books of ahadeeth such as Sahih al-Bukhari as well the following saying of the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him):

> "When one of you eats some food, let him say Bismillah, and if he
>   forgets to do so at the beginning, let him say Bismillah fi awwalihi
>   wa aakhirihi (In the name of Allah at the beginning and end)"

Jami at-Tirmidhi

I have not come across a hadeeth where it is mentioned that Bismillah should be said thrice before eating. Once is the sunnah and that is sufficient, Insha Allah.

And Allah knows best

May Allah bless you with goodness, ameen

wa assalam

Answer (score 3):

This hadith puts some light on this

[Sahih Bukari - Book 7 - Hadith no - 288](http://www.quranexplorer.com/hadith/english/Hadith/bukhari/007.065.288.html) says -

> Narrated 'Umar bin Abi Salama:
>
> I was a boy under the care of Allah's Apostle and my hand used to go around the dish while I was eating. So Allah's Apostle said to me, 'O boy! **Mention the Name of Allah** and eat with your right hand, and eat of the dish what is nearer to you." Since then I have applied those instructions when eating.

Saying it 3 times instead of 1 would be a more good deed.

Comment: the question is about "bismillahi wa'alaa barakatillah "

Answer (score 0):

Salaam Walaikum
Why not say "Bismillah" and then
Inna Allaha huwa arrazzaquthoo alquwwati almateen

Which means
In the Name of Allah
Indeed, Allah ˹alone˺ is the Supreme Provider—Lord of all Power, Ever Mighty.

Answer (score -1):

As-salaamu alaykum Wa-rahmatulllaahi Wa-barakatuhu.. It is better to say Bismillaah 1 time as per the instruction we get from those ahadith.. Saying it 3 times cannot be a more good deed unless we get a clear Sahih hadith for doing so particularly while eating.. Eg. Sujood is such a great act of worship but can we make 8 Sujoods in 2 rakat instead of 4 thinking that it can be a more good deed? In fact we'll be held accountable for doing such innovations in Deen..